# Detect mouseover of non-square part of an Image

Tags: c#, xna, shapes

So I am working on a Risk type game in XNA/C#. I have a map, similar [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdW9a.png), and I need to be able to detect mouseovers on each territory (number). If these areas were squares, it would be easy, as they could each be represented by a rectangle. However, they are different size polygons. Is there a polygon shape that behaves similar to a square? If there isn't, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sugest this:attach color to each number, recreate your picture in these colors: every shape will be in its particular color. Dont draw it onscreen, use it only as reference map. And when the user clicks or moves mouse over your original map, you just simply project mouse coordinates into the color map, check the color of pixel laying under the mouse and because you have each color associated to number of territory...

Comment: I am not sure. When working with bitmap stored in Texture2D it is like so:Texture2D tex;

Color[] texColors = new Color[height * width];
tex.GetData(texColors);

Comment: This sounds easy to think about, but less than ideal for the computer. Make sure you don't draw with anti aliasing. Personally I'd go for a mathematical model of the space rather than a bitmap.

Comment: The mathematical approach is sophisticated, but it is also maybe too sophisticated. The reference color map is not drawn itself, i think antialising will not mess it or interfere with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not c# specific (as I've never written anything in the language, so no idea of what apis there are), though there are 2 algorithms that come to mind for detecting if a point is inside a polygon (which can be used to detect if a mouse point is over another polygon/map shape).

One is based on raycasting, where you cast a ray in 1 direction from the (mouse) point to "infinity" (edge of the board in this case) and count the number of times it crosses the polygon's edges. If it is odd, then the point is inside the polygon, if it is even, then the point is outside of the polygon.

A wiki link to it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm

The other algorithm that comes to mind works only for triangles I think but it can be more simple to implement I think (taking a quick glance at your shapes, I think they can easily be broken down into triangles and some are already triangles). It is to do with checking if the point is on the same (internal) "side" of all the edges in the triangle. To find out what "side" a point is on vs an edge, you'd take create 2 vectors, the first vector would be the edge itself (made up of 2 points) and the other vector would be the first point of that edge to the input point, then calculate the cross product of those 2 vectors. The result will be negative or positive, which can be used to determine the "direction".

A link to it: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html
(On that page is another algorithm that can also work for triangles)

Answer (score 0):

Hit testing on a polygon is not so difficult to do in real time. You could use a KD-Tree for optimisation if the map is huge. Otherwise find a simple `Contains` method for a polygon and use that. I have one on another computer. Let me know if you'd like it.